# redirect 301 all traffic to homepage

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect all traffic request uri to homepage of my wordpress page.
I try override default wordpress, but cant get this to work any one can help in this ?

I try following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /wordpress/

RewriteBase /

<If "%{REQUEST_URI} != 'http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/'">
    Redirect 301 / http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/
</if>

#RewriteRule (.*) http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/ [R=301,L]




RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I don't get it since it seems your explanation and code are doing the opposite. Do you want `/wordpress/` to redirect to `/` or vice versa ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule just below `RewriteBase` line:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+wordpress/\S [NC]
RewriteRule .+ /wordpress/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Now just I have to understand \S and .+ :) if you carry to explain I will be much thankful.

Comment: Sure I can explain. `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /wordpress/file HTTP/1.1`. So `\s` matches spaces after `GET` and `/+` matches 1 or more slashes after first space. Last `\S` makes sure to match at least one non-space character after `/wordpress/`.